# Twilio nodejs undefined messages create

Tags: node.js, typescript, twilio

I'm trying to send SMS using Twilio nodejs (with Typescript) but, for some reason, I cannot access to  create method on messages property (as described in the documentation).

```
const TWILIO_CLIENT = require('twilio');
let twilioClient = new TWILIO_CLIENT(accountSid, authToken);
let result = await twilioClient.messages.create(smsData);
```

I get a undefined when trying to access create method, and when I log messages endpoint it only shows my the defined accountSid: { accountSid: "..." }

What could it be?

Comment: That's odd. What version of `twilio` do you have installed?

Comment: @philnash the lastest

Comment: What does your smsData object look like?  Can you provide more code (except your secure tokens, of course)?